# How many Pseudonode can we create on standalone machine using hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, nosql

how many Pseudo node can we create on standalone machine in hadoop?
does it relate to replication factor while configuring it?

HDFS is NOSQL? (is it correct)

Comment: Hi roshan, 
Are you asking for configuring Pseudonde cluster ?? IF means yes we can!

Comment: thanks for reply karthik
i mean how many max number of cluster we can form in dual core processor

Comment: Well, roshan !! Yarn performance not only depends on the Cores also depends on RAM and number of disk. For Pseudo node of 8 GB RAM 2 cores and 1 Disk, Recommended containers are 4 per node !!! 2 core can handle the number of process depend on the above 3 factors to calculate that recommendations refer - http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.0.9.1/bk_installing_manually_book/content/rpm-chap1-11.html 
Same thing should be followed on all node in multi cluster.